# No space between Characters in my application

Tags: html, css

For few days in my application all the characters are displaying as below:

[Font displaying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgVvr.jpg)

I don't understand why it  is behaving like this.
Could you please help me to solve this issue.

I am using Grails and Groovy framework, Java 1.6, GSP files.

I thought this was a browser compatibility issue so I have added below lines of code in all gsp files of application:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=5; IE=7; IE=9; IE=8; IE=10; IE=11; IE=Edge" />
<meta name="layout" content="viewport"/>
```

When I run the application it's considering the default IE is 5 in websphere server, but when I run through my local GGTS the default IE is edge. I don't know why?

Comment: <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=5; IE=7; IE=9; IE=8; IE=10; IE=11; IE=Edge" />
    <meta name="layout" content="viewport"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your support. I have change the browser setting and not application is working.

I have uncheck the Display intranet check box and remove site name from web site you have added.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7meO2.png)

Answer (score 0):

Java 1.6?  IE 5?  Impressive backwards compatibility!

Regardless the problem is probably from some CSS on your page.  In a newer browser (Edge is fine, or try Firefox or Chrome) inspect your page and see if you have any CSS property set that you do not want.  For example, maybe `letter-spacing`?

It could definitely be something else, but style-related problems usually come from CSS.

Comment: I have found some css property like latter-spacing. Priviously it is  1px so I have increased to 2px but no use.

Comment: Shall I remove this property from css file?

Comment: I would recommend understanding your styling, but if this property is having an impact that you do not want, you can certainly remove it.